# puppet on amazon ec2: could not change hostname

Tags: debian, amazon-ec2, puppet, facter

I'm running ec2 debian instance and trying to get puppet working on it. I'd like my hostnames to be something more readable, so I've changed `/etc/hostname`, run `/etc/init.d/hostname.sh start` and I can see my human-readable hostname in the prompt. Every other app seems to be working fine with it, but not puppet (and actually it seems it's facter problem):

```
$ cat /etc/hostname 
service.XXX.com
$ hostname
service.XXX.com
$ facter | egrep '(host|domain)'
domain => compute-1.amazonaws.com
hostname => ec2-107-22-XXX-XXX
$ cat /etc/debian_version 
6.0.1
```

I've already cheched facter code and it seems it does not anything more than parsing `hostname` output. Where is this thing come from? I want my hostnames!

Comment: Had the same hostname issue and adding it as first alias in hosts fixed the problem for me too. Debian Squeeze.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blah, it seems it parses /etc/hosts and my beautiful hostname should be the first alias for '127.0.0.1' (`127.0.0.1 service.XXX.com localhost localhost.localdomain ...`). Anyone knows, is this expected behavior?

I'm still not sure where ec2-blah-blah-blah comes from, but it seems the issue is resolved.

Comment: Puppet tries to get the reverse to the IP address -- I'm surprised `127.0.0.1` did it for you. It also looks up `/etc/resolv.conf` for the domain. Have you tried just grepping `ec2-...` on `/etc` to see what configuration contains that?